# React routing with a top navigation bar

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm currently working on setting up React routing for my application and would like to integrate a top navigation bar. Here's how I've structured my routing using createBrowserRouter:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        element: <><TopNavbar /> <Outlet/></>,
        children:[
            {
                path: "/",
                element: <Home />,
            },
            {
                path: "/login",
                element: <Login />,
            },
        ]
    },
]);
```

In this setup, I've included the TopNavbar component and the  within the main router element, with child routes defined for Home and Login.

I'm curious about the best practices for integrating a top navigation bar with React routing. Is my approach considered a good practice, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: This approach seems fine to me. Generally speaking, asking for "best X" is considered subjective and off-topic for Stackoverflow. Is there a more specific issue or concern you have with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best practices in React development, especially when it comes to routing, is to separate concerns by modularizing your code. This not only makes your application more maintainable but also easier to understand for new developers or contributors to your project. Here's how you can apply these principles to your scenario:

1. **Modular Routing:** Split your routing logic into its own function or component. This keeps your main app clutter-free and makes it easy to adjust routes on the fly, whether due to changes in user status or permissions.
2. **Layout Component**: Shift to using a layout component, say AppLayout, that wraps around your pages. Include your header, footer, and an  for the main content in this component. This setup clarifies your site's structure and makes future layout changes a breeze, all without messing with your routing setup.
3. **Router Builder Strategy:** Lean on a RouterBuilder function for your routing setup. This approach lets you organize your route definitions in one place, making your code cleaner and easier to maintain.

App.tsx:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import RouterBuilder from './App.router';

const App = () => {
  const routes = useMemo(() => RouterBuilder(), []);

  return <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} />;
};
```

App.router.tsx:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './LoginPage';
import HomePage from './HomePage';
import AppLayout from './App.layout';

const RouterBuilder = () => {
  const generalRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: <LoginPage />,
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <HomePage />,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/" replace />,
    },
  ];

  const routes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
      element: <AppLayout />,
      children: generalRoutes,
    },
  ];

  return routes;
};

export default RouterBuilder;
```

App.layout.tsx:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from '@/layout/Header';
import Footer from '@/layout/Footer';

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </Suspense>
  );
};

export default React.memo(AppLayout);
```

To sum up, your initial routing approach incorporating a top navigation bar directly within your React Router setup is totally valid and functional. However, by adopting to logic I mentioned, you can further enhance your application’s routing architecture. This method simplifies route management, centralizing definitions and potentially making future adjustments or expansions more straightforward.